# How can i run script in firebase automatically

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made an App and I want delete a story automatically after 24 hours. I can make it, but user should open app to check.

Now how can i check from firebase server without open app? I think it something like run script in server without stop.

I use firebase realtime database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Firebase's [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions.)

Schedule Functions on an interval to delete a story:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 
minutes').onRun((context) => {
  // your code to delete something
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
  return null;
});
```

Reference to scheduling Cloud Functions:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions